# Tell Cucumber tests to run on https

Tags: https, cucumber, selenium-rc, webrat

I am running cucumber tests with Webrat in external mode that is using Selenium.  In production we are running behind https and so we are required to run our cucumber tests on https.

Is there any place we can specify that cucumber, webrat, or selenium needs to be using https?  Ideally this could be specified through a parameter that is given to Webrat.

I have seen some stuff that looks like it might be possible if I override the default SeleniumClientDriver that comes bundled under the selenium.rb file.

env.rb =>

```
Webrat.configure do |config|
    config.mode = :selenium
    config.aplication_address = 'localhost'
    config.aplication_port = 11090
    config.selenium_server_address = 'localhost'
    config.selenium_server_port = 4444
    config.selenium_browser_key = '*iexploreproxy'
    config.application_framework = :external
end

World do
    session = Webrat::SeleniumSession.new
    session.extend(Webrat::Methods)
    session.extend(Webrat::Selenium::Methods)
    session.extend(Webrat::Selenium::Matchers)
    session        
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently is not something that the webrat team has decided to support.

So a team member changed the source to allow that this can be specified through env.rb properties.  The pull request can be found [here](https://github.com/brynary/webrat/pull/58).